# Why is this not printing console.log(score) to the console?

Tags: javascript, html

The console.log(score) won't print to the console. I have tried to place it outside the form tag and everywhere else but still nothing prints

```js
const correctAnswers = ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B'];

const form = document.querySelector('.quiz-form');


form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  let score = 0;
  const userAnswers = [form.q1.value, form.q2.value, form.q3.value, form.q4.value];

  //check answers
  userAnswers.forEach((answer, index) => {
    if (answer === correctAnswers[index]) {
      score += 25;
    }
  });
  console.log(score);

});
```

```html
<form class="quiz-form text-light">
  <div class="my-5">
    <p class="lead font-weight-normal">1.How do you give a ninja directions?</p>
    <div class="form-check my-2 text-white-50">
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="A" checked>
      <label class="form-check-label">Show them a map</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check my-2 text-white-50">
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="B">
      <label class="form-check-label">A ninja will find you</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--second-->
  <div class="my-5">
    <p class="lead font-weight-normal">2.If a ninja has three apples and give one away, how many does he have?</p>
    <div class="form-check my-2 text-white-50">
      <input type="radio" name="q2" value="A" checked>
      <label class="form-check-label">one apple</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check my-2 text-white-50">
      <input type="radio" name="q2" value="B">
      <label class="form-check-label">two apples</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--end of second-->
```

Comment: Where is the submit button for the form?

Comment: It works perfectly. All you need is to add a submit button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a "submit" listener, so you need a "submit" event to trigger it (such as from `<input type="submit" />`).

In the sample code, since there are no `q3` and `q4`, I commented them out from the `userAnswers` array.

**Edited:**
If you want to log the score right away as well as whenever the form is submitted, you can just name the function -- here I named it `printScore` -- and invoke it by name in both situations.

```js
const correctAnswers = ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B'];
const form = document.querySelector('.quiz-form');

form.addEventListener('submit', printScore); // Calls printScore when form is submitted
printScore(); // Calls printScore once immediately

function printScore(e){
  
  // Skips the call to preventDefault for the initial call
  if(e){ e.preventDefault(); }
  
  let score = 0;
  const userAnswers = [form.q1.value, form.q2.value //, form.q3.value, form.q4.value
  ];
  //check answers
  userAnswers.forEach((answer, index) => {
    if (answer === correctAnswers[index]) {
      score += 25;
    }
  });

  // Helps make sure the browser will log something even if it's `0` 
  let scoreString = "" + score;
  console.log("current score: " + scoreString);
};
```

```html
<form class="quiz-form text-light">

  <div class="my-5">
    <p class="lead font-weight-normal">1.How do you give a ninja directions?</p>
    <div class="form-check my-2 text-white-50">
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="A" checked>
      <label class="form-check-label">Show them a map</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check my-2 text-white-50">
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="B">
      <label class="form-check-label">A ninja will find you</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="my-5">
    <p class="lead font-weight-normal">2.If a ninja has three apples and give one away, how many does he have?</p>
    <div class="form-check my-2 text-white-50">
      <input type="radio" name="q2" value="A" checked>
      <label class="form-check-label">one apple</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check my-2 text-white-50">
      <input type="radio" name="q2" value="B">
      <label class="form-check-label">two apples</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  
   <input type="submit" value="submit" />

</form>
```

Comment: hi, sorry I did not add the code with the submit button. I do have this in my fourth question:</div>
    </div>

    <div class="text-center">
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-light">
    </div>
    <!--end of fourth-->

Comment: I am wondering why it doesn't print 0 as the starting score in the console. It just shows blank and it should show zero when all answers are wrong and 100 if all the answers are right but it's just blank

Comment: Ah, ok. See my edits. The score gets printed when the script first runs before the user ever clicks the button. And what gets printed is defined more explicitly so the browser is less likely to "decide" you don't actually need to see the value in the console.

Comment: hi it still doesn't work. Could you have a look at the entire code here:https://jsbin.com/niyonaf/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: Okay, what's not working? (And what browser are you using?)

Comment: thank you)) I am using chrome. re: what's not working. It doesn't console.log anything when i click on submit.

Comment: When I go to your jsbin and click submit, both the jsbin console and the Chrome developer tools console log `current score: 0`...

Comment: yes, that's kind of odd. it logs 50 as well now even when all B's are selected

Comment: it works now on my original! didn't link js properly. used <script type> instead of src